What type of contractor do I need to investigate exterior air leaks?
Recently we had water damage in our downstairs ceiling. Thought it was from a leak in the upstairs bathroom (since it is roughly below there), but when remediation team came out and cut out the drywall, it turns out that our metal HVAC ducts had been slowly gathering condensation to the point where they rusted out at the bottom and leaked through. After removing mold and drying everything out, they recommended we get an HVAC person out. HVAC service company comes out and says that there must be unconditioned air getting to the ducts causing them to sweat. He's not sure exactly where that would be coming from, although he did point to some little vent caps on the outside of the house, kind've under the gutters on our lower roof. Not exactly sure what those are, but think it may be where the downstairs bathroom fan vents out? Also said that they deal with HVAC system and small ductwork issues, but not replacing all ductwork throughout a house. He said we would need to get a contractor to deal with this issue.
So I guess my question is what type of contractor(s) do I call to deal with the following three things:
Determining/sealing any places where unconditioned air might be getting in to the house and coming in contact with the ducts, causing them to sweat;
Replacing the rusted ductwork with new ductwork;
Insulating the new ductwork (the remediation company removed some old insulation around the ducts that had become moldy; also, this is an old house (1940) and I'm sure it probably had old, worn out insulation which may have been part of the problem with the ducts getting exposed to unconditioned air in the first place).
Appreciate any insights, but please no DIY recommendations (that is not me, I need to hire a professional).

You need an HVAC company.   You can call around and some will do insulation too - a lot of HVAC companies have turned into "green services" companies.
If none in your area do this then you need HVAC and an insulation company (although insulation is very DIY).    I would not hire a general contractor or a contractor for this type of work.


So I guess my question is what type of contractor(s) do I call

To start, do a web search for 'Energy Efficiency Experts'. There should be several in your area. They can and will do a total energy efficiency eval of your house. They will also know which, if any, of their services may be covered by either government subsidies or by your local electric/gas company.
The fun starts when they complete the analysis and give you their recommendations. My guess is that, unless there was extensive renovation done, a house built in the 40s will probably leak air like a sieve.
As was mentioned by DMoore there may be easy DIY fixes that would save on some of the costs, such as, sealing leaks around windows and doors.
A few other thoughts:

I don't know the structure of your house but those 'little vent caps' that seem to be under the soffit may be part of the roof venting system to expel heat and, if so, should not be blocked. They should be allowing exterior air to flow through the crawl space under the roof and out through roof vents. Typically, the AC ductwork would not pass through this area for obvious reasons. But with an 80+ year old house - who knows what was done when the AC was installed?
After the energy efficiency/air flow eval is complete you'll probably have to bring in a HVAC company to correct the ductwork issues. Many 1940 homes did not have forced hot air so the AC work was likely a retrofit and you could have ductwork in places where it may be difficult to insulate against unconditioned air. If that's the case, make sure that the company that does the evaluation makes specific recommendations on how/where the ductwork should be run.


My power company has a "home efficiency" audit that includes a blower door test.  The blower door test is basically sticking a fan in one of the doorways, sealing around it, and running the fan to generate a low pressure area in the house.  Then literally walk around and feel the leaks with one's hands.
In the US, those tests are often free (the government pays for them).  Just check the electric company's web site for it.  Not sure about other countries.
